# Joins in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on generating quarterly royalty reports for authors. I have a Report model (not backed by a database table) that I'm using to display the report for specific authors based on the year and quarter. I'm routing that to `author/:author_id/:reports/:year/:quarter`

But I'm using this:

```
@line_items_totals = LineItem.where(:order_id => @orders, :product_id => @author_products).order("product_id ASC").sum(:quantity, :group => :product_id)
```

That returns a hash with the product id as the key and the total quantity sold for all that products line items, for the given time period, like this:

```
#<Enumerator: {1=>2865, 2=>4068, 4=>50, 5=>60, 9=>22}>
```

the query it produces is:

```
SELECT SUM("line_items"."quantity") AS sum_quantity, product_id AS product_id 
FROM "line_items" 
WHERE ("line_items"."order_id" IN (10, 12, 15, 16)) 
AND ("line_items"."product_id" IN (2, 4, 1, 5, 9)) 
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY product_id ASC
```

What I need, though, is the product title instead of the ID. Not having much luck. I tried using `.joins` -- but it didn't seem to work, because of the sum method in the query.

Comment: I saw your earlier question and wanted to ask you about your associations. Does `LineItem` have many `Products` or just one?

Comment: it's currently belongs_to :product ... but, each line item is only associated with one product. It's the order that has_many: line_items and therefore has_many: products through line_items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do:

```
ListItem.other_stuff.joins(:product).group(:product_id).select('sum(line_items.quantity) as total_quantity, products.title')
```

or

```
LineItem.other_stuff.group(:product_id).select('sum(quantity) as total_quantity, (select title from products where products.id == product_id) as title)')
```

then you can access title and total_quantity as LineItem properties:

```
item.title
item.total_quantity.to_i
```

ActiveRecord or adapter dynamically define properties according to selected columns, even though there are no such columns in the table. Also notice, that for unknown reason MySQL adapter creates this dynamic attributes with String type, instead of Fixnum as you would expect (while SQLite adapter uses proper types). So you have to cast it manually, like i shown above.

Comment: This is working, but I'm having trouble accessing the sum value in the view. I tried:<% @line_items_totals.each do |product, line_item | %>
  <h3><%= product.title %> <%= line_item.sum %></h3>
<% end %>

Comment: also tried product.sum(line_items.quantity) ... not working either.

Comment: I changed `sum(line_items.quantity)` to `sum(line_items.quantity) as lines_sum` ... which I can now access in my view as product.lines_sum. So all is good now. Thanks!

Comment: @Final Draft, You are welcome, also take into consideration my comment about type casting (i've updated the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try the order by the product title like this:

**Updated the code**

```
@line_items_totals = LineItem.where(:order_id => @orders, :product_id => @author_products).joins(:product).order("product_id ASC").group('products.title').sum(:quantity)
```

This should be equal with this:

```
@line_items_totals = LineItem.where(:order_id => @orders, :product_id => @author_products).joins(:product).order("product_id ASC").sum(:quantity, :group => 'products.title')
```